# "some of its usages includes ..." vs "some of its usages include ..."

Tags: grammatical-number

When should I use

> "some of its usages includes ..."

and when I should use

> "some of its usages include: ...".

I have googled both, and it seems both are in use.

Comment: If *foos* is a stand-in for a plural noun, I believe that you should use *include*.

Comment: You should not say either; include has the sense of some 'built in'. Say "Its foos include A, B, C" or "Some of its foos are A, B, C".

Comment: It's not the topic of the question, but I think it likely that 'uses' would work better than 'usages' in this context. See http://blogs.transparent.com/english/use-versus-usage/

Comment: @DamkerngT.What is *foos*?

Comment: @Man_From_India I have updated the question. foos is plural form of foo!

Comment: @MrTheWalrus Thanks, What about "applications"

Comment: @StoneyB I see you use both single and double quote in your comment. What is the reason behind that? (I wonder I should say "behind that" or "behind this" !)

Comment: @PrinceOfPersia 'applications' sounds correct to me - synonymous with 'uses'.

Comment: @Prince of Persia  Whimsy? ... 'This' for marked use, "this" for (quasi-)quotation.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common grammatical error to match the verb with the object of a descriptive prepositional phrase (in this case "usages" and "include") rather than with the subject of the sentence.  In this particular case, though, your second wording is correct because the word "Some" is an implied plural - it's several usages and not just one, or else they would have specifically stated it was just one usage, and then the sentence would read, "One of its usages includes..." because "one" would be the singular subject and "includes" would be the singular form of the verb.

To use another example that is pretty obvious, "The people who work in that building bring their lunch from home," is correct because "people" is the plural subject and "eat" is the plural form of the verb.  A building would not bring a lunch, so you would never be confused about that sentence since it would not make sense any other way.

Rewording these types of sentences and trying your best never to separate the subject and the verb will help eliminate any confusion.

General Google searches are a bad source of grammar instruction because many people who write web pages do not use perfect English grammar or spelling.  I highly recommend the Purdue Online Writing Lab, https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/index.html, as a reputable source of information about English grammar and usage.

Answer (score 0):

A natural and idiomatic way to say this would be soemthign like:

> X is a powerful technique. Its uses include {list of uses}.

"Include" implies that what follows is an incomplete list, so "some" is redundant. "uses" is plural because the list includes more than one item. thus the verb form is "include" to agree with "uses".

The from "includes" is used when discussing whether a particular item is part of the list, as I did in the previous paragraph of this answer. Another example:

> Smith says that X is not part of the category Y, Jones, however, includes X among the Y.

The form "includes" can al;so be used when discussign a subcategory in relation to the larger category:

> The set of real numbers includes all the rational numbers.